# Error 211 'HiddenFor' is not a member of 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am continually getting this error - Error 211 'HiddenFor' is not a member of 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'.  - on all of my pages.

** This isn't just happening to Hidden for -- but all html. functions

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be going to System.Web.WebPages, but System.Web.Mvc.  There is a webpages one, but that is for ASP.NET web pages, a separate framework.  It's true that some pieces overlap, but not HtmlHelper.  Check your config file to make sure your mappings are OK, and pointing to the correct versions of MVC and of the web pages framework.

Also check that your DLL references are valid (no exclamation points that VS is noting).